# How can I prevent unrecoverable photo deletions on Android without a cloud service?

Tags: data-recovery, camera, photos

I don't want to set up Google photos to back up to the cloud for privacy reasons.

Recently I noticed that with the default Android camera app, and the default Google Photos app, the "Trash" is only used if you have the app set up to sync with your cloud service.

This means that any photo that's deleted from the camera roll—for example, by swiping from the camera to view the photos just taken, and then swiping down—is immediately unrecoverable.  (There is an "undo" button briefly visible, and that's all.)

By contrast, in iOS (which my family members are more used to), any photo that you delete will go to the "Trash" where it will only be actually removed after 30 days, giving plenty of time to recover from any accidents or mistakes.  (And in iOS, this feature doesn't require iCloud use at all.)

**How can I set up my Android devices to mimic this functionality, so that photos deleted from the camera roll, or from the photos app, are still preserved for an additional 30 days unless special action is taken?**

(I'm running a Nexus 7 with Android 6.0.1, but we have a couple other Android devices in the house that I would probably apply the answers to if I can.)

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use Google Photos app when you don't  want to sync your photos? There are plenty of aesthetically and functionally superior  gallery apps in Play Store which offer trash feature. For the Camera, I suppose you either switch to a camera app which offers trash feature, or, you setup an automation app which copies the image, the moment it is captured, to a certain location other than default DCIM folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a separate app to get this functionality. Since you don't want to use cloud services, this app can help you recover your deleted photos: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.baloota.dumpster&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You need a Recycling Bin Application..
IOS uses a Recycling Bin, similar to that of a PC..

Android has no such features..

You can download applications that allow you to use the Share function to Send files to a Recycling Bin...